# On button click uri intent works in android 4.1.2, but does not work on android 2.3.7

Tags: java, android, url, android-intent, uri

I have the following Activity:

```
     package com.example.myapp;

     import android.net.Uri;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.content.ComponentName;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.content.SharedPreferences;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
     import android.view.animation.Animation;
     import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
     import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.ImageButton;
     import android.widget.ScrollView;
     import android.widget.Toast;

     public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {

 // Animation
     Animation animFadein;
     Animation animFadeout;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_start);

// load the animation
    animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade_in);
    animFadeout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade_out);

    // set animation listener
    animFadein.setAnimationListener(this);

ImageButton homepage =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.homepage);
    ImageButton new_b =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.new_b);
    ImageButton view_b =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.view_b);
    ImageButton home_b =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home_b);
    ImageButton info_b =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.info_b);
    Button back_b =(Button)findViewById(R.id.back_b);
    Button site =(Button)findViewById(R.id.site);

    homepage.startAnimation(animFadein);

    //Click on screen to start
    homepage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override    
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View homepage = (View)findViewById(R.id.homepage);
        View startpage = (View)findViewById(R.id.startpage);
        homepage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        homepage.startAnimation(animFadeout);
        startpage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        startpage.setAnimation(animFadein);};});  

    new_b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SharedPreferences values = getSharedPreferences("valoar", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = values.edit();
        editor.clear(); 
        editor.commit();
        View startpage = (View)findViewById(R.id.startpage);
        startpage.setAnimation(animFadeout);
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,QuestionsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);}});



    home_b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override    
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View homepage = (View)findViewById(R.id.homepage);
        View startpage = (View)findViewById(R.id.startpage);
        homepage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        homepage.startAnimation(animFadein);
        startpage.startAnimation(animFadeout);
        startpage.setVisibility(View.GONE);};}); 

    info_b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override    
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View startpage = (View)findViewById(R.id.startpage);
            View infopage = (View)findViewById(R.id.infopage);
            ScrollView info_s = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.info_s);
            infopage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            info_s.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            infopage.startAnimation(animFadein);
            startpage.startAnimation(animFadeout);
            startpage.setVisibility(View.GONE);};});

    back_b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override    
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View startpage = (View)findViewById(R.id.startpage);
            View infopage = (View)findViewById(R.id.infopage);
            ScrollView info_s = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.info_s);
            infopage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            info_s.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            infopage.startAnimation(animFadeout);
            startpage.startAnimation(animFadein);
            startpage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);};});

    **site.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent internetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://www.i-amapp.com"));
                internetIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser","com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
                internetIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(internetIntent);};});**



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/**
 * Back button listener.
 * Will close the application if the back button pressed twice.
 */
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    int backButtonCount = 0;
    if(backButtonCount  >= 1)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press the x button to close the application.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        backButtonCount++;
    }
}
```

}

It works very well in android 4.1.2, but in android 2.3.7 it crashes, and Logcat displays:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(2172): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(2172): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
E/AndroidRuntime(2172): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(2172): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(2172): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at com.example.myapp.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     ... 11 more
D/dalvikvm(3117): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 61K, 50% free 2724K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 44ms
D/dalvikvm(3117): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 4K, 50% free 2730K/5379K, external 507K/513K, paused 43ms
D/dalvikvm(3117): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 50% free 2736K/5379K, external 1068K/1524K, paused 43ms
D/dalvikvm(3117): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1K, 50% free 2741K/5379K, external 1669K/2086K, paused
```

This is all that logcat is displaying. I can't figure out what is the problem!
Why does it crash in android 2.3?

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace, including the nested "caused by" NPE exception

Comment: You have a Null Pointer Exception. Post your log and let's see what is not initialised here. Probably you are using a fairly new method to initialise an object that's not working in old versions.

Comment: maybe you're using something that only usable from a certain API level ?